# Inheritance and function overriding in Python

Tags: python, oop

In python, if class C inherits from two other classes C(A,B), and A and B have methods with identical names but different return values, which value will that method return on C?

Comment: Did you write code to try this? What happened?

Comment: Also, the docs are helpful. See [Multiple Inheritance](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#multiple-inheritance).

Comment: @jarmod class A method is called and not B

Comment: Right, but if you also tested `class C(B, A):` then you'd find a different result (B is called, not A) and you might then infer that the ordering is in fact deterministic, which would lead you to research Python multiple inheritance (link provided earlier) which would lead you to MRO. PS for future questions, I'd encourage you to include code, even if it's simplistic - Stack Overflow works better when we're all looking at the same code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Inherits two methods" isn't quite accurate. What happens is that `C` has a *method resolution order* (MRO), which is the list `[C, A, B, object]`. If you attempt to access a method that `C` does not define or override, the MRO determines which class will be checked next. If the desired method is defined in `A`, it shadows a method with the same name in `B`.

```
>>> class A:
...   def foo(self):
...     print("In A.foo")
...
>>> class B:
...   def foo(self):
...     print("In B.foo")
...
>>> class C(A, B):
...   pass
...
>>> C.mro()
[<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class 'object'>]
>>> C().foo()
In A.foo
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro

Answer (score 0):

MRO order will be followed now, if you inherit A and B in C, then preference order goes from left to right, so, A will be prefered and method of A will be called instead of B